# Как лучше хранить статьи и сообщения в базе данных

Tags: java

Решил сделать сайт где будут статьи как на хабре(оооочень грубо говоря) и сообщения пользователей. И вот какой самый лучший вариант хранения их. Неуверен является ли в mysql nvarchar() лучшим вариантом. Подходят идеи также связанные с монго или лучше кафка.

Comment: Вы про личные сообщения юзер-юзер или про комментарии к статьям? Если последнее - посмотрите исходники тут например (в подвале): https://dont-play-with-google.com/

Comment: А вообще у вас вопрос слишком широкий. Возможно, вам стоит его переформулировать в вид "Какой тип для колонки использовать для хранения больших текстов в БД"

Comment: юзер к юзеру рассматриваю

Comment: В таком случае это никак не относится к статьям и, пожалуй, к типам данных. Возможно, вам стоит задать по отдельному вопросу по каждому из вопросов.

Comment: мне нужно хранить отдельно статьи, и отдельно сообщения пользователей

Comment: В таком случае можно упоминание о сообщениях удалить из вопроса, если он у вас о хранении больших текстов

Comment: не понимаю почему удалить, сообщения среднего размера как в обычном чате

Comment: Ну храните статьи не в varchar а в text, в чем проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно для статей лучше хранить данные в монго а для сообщений в mysql